# OS (Windows7) not detected when installing

Tags: system-installation, windows-7

When I try to install the latest version of Ubuntu and I have to choose the type of installation it appears a message in the top of the screen that says I have no OS in the PC, but I have Windows 7 installed. Any idea why the program don't recognizes it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into BIOS

Set the SATA mode to IDE

Set the SATA3 mode to AHCI

Install. You will need to change these settings back when you boot into Windows and vice versa, as Windows cannot boot with these settings.

It is likely the bootloader will not show up, but that can be fixed easily by first typing sudo fdisk `-l` in a Terminal

Then, run `sudo mount /dev/STEP_5_OUTPUT /mnt` && `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda`

Now you should be able to boot, but be sure to revert the changes to BIOS to boot Windows and vice versa.